# How to call a method every X seconds in Rails?

Tags: ruby, timer

How can I call a method say every 10 seconds? For example, I would like to call the `aMethod` of class `MyFile` every 10 seconds:

```
class MyFile
  def aMethod
    p 'hi there'
  end
end
```

How can I accomplish this? My Production environment is Windows, and I don't have Ruby/Rails installed on the Production server (the application is jruby and will be deployed as a WAR package onto a Tomcat webserver).

Comment: I would try using the [rufus-scheduler gem](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). The `scheduler.every ... do ... end` sample listed there seems what you need.

Comment: `def aMethod; p 'hi there'; end; while true; aMethod; sleep 1; end`

Comment: @w0lf, Thank you very much -- yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm...wish I could 'upvote' you/your answer.

Comment: @AliKhan I can't add this as an answer, because the question was marked as a duplicate. Anyway, I'm glad my suggestion worked.